# How to update values in multiple documents as a transaction in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Firestore database for Android that tracks the position and wait time of all entries in a queue. Each queue is a Collection, and each user's entry is represented by a Document in that collection.

My goal is to decrement the position value for every Document in the Collection simultaneously.

Ideally, I would like to update each value using a transaction because I don't have the resources to use Firestore's cloud functions.

However, I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the best way to go about it:

```
CollectionReference entryRef = ref.collection("entries");
List<String> entryIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Long> positions = new ArrayList<Long>();

entryRef.get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    entryIDs.add(document.getId());
                    positions.add(document.getLong("position"));
                }
            }
        }
});

for (int i = 0; i < entryIDs.size(); i++) {
    transaction.update(entryRef.document(entryIDs.get(i)), "position", positions.get(i));
}
```

Is there a better way to decrement a value in multiple documents at the same time?

Comment: You'll want to use the [`batch()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#batch()) to create a [WriteBatch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/WriteBatch) and then update each document using [`FieldValue.increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#increment(long)) (with a negative value)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll hydrate it later today when I get the chance. At least it helps get them going while I'm busy.

Comment: @samthecodingman Thank you for the tip, though wouldn't using `batch()` come with the risk of the database changing while the process is ongoing? I was hoping to use transactions because there could be users joining a queue at any time.

Comment: @VanillaMilkshakes A batch and a transaction are largely the same behind the scenes. Use a transaction when you also need to **read** some of the data that you're writing, and a batch when you don't. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for clarifying. 

The introduction video gave me the impression that batch writes wouldn't be useful if I wanted to use the most up-to-date version of the data.

(in the case here, the position values could be constantly changing due to users joining and leaving)